# Reset a builtin function

Tags: linux, reset, built-in

I have the following code in my `.bashrc` file:

```
function cd {
builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

which overwrites `cd` to always execute the `ls` command immediately after.

Short of removing it and rerunning the file, what can I do to reset the `cd` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unset` takes a `-f` flag to unset a function definition.

```
unset -f cd
```